# How to remove duplicate dom elements from body?

Tags: javascript

I have cloned div duplicate elements in body with the class name "combo". I need to remove all duplicates except the original div element

Comment: Only using native JavaScript?

Comment: There must be some difference between the original and cloned element. if it so, then use filter method.

Comment: When you clone those elements you could consider giving them another class name in addition to 'combo'.

Comment: @Jack: cf my answer: it's been suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fn = function(originalEl){

    var els = document.querySelectorAll('.combo');

    for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++){
        if( els[i] !== originalEl ){
            els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: perhaps add `index !== 0`, to avoid deleting all of the elements

Comment: That assumes the original is the first item in the document. The cloned one might have been inserted before it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that cloned objects will have the same attributes as the original, so it's rather hard to distinguish them, however, you could try this:

```
(function()
{
                   //or indeed: querySelector('.combo') which returns a single DOM ref
    var original = document.querySelectorAll('.combo')[0];//reference to the original
    //clone and add
    function removeClones()
    {
        var i,all = document.querySelectorAll('.combo');
        for(i=0;i<all.length;i++)
        {
            if (all[i] !== original)
            {//this is a clone
                all[i].parentNode.removeChild(all[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}());
```

That should do it. An alternative method would be to add a class to the clones, prior to appending them to the DOM:

```
var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
clone.className += ' combo-clone';
//then, to remove:
var clones = document.querySelectorAll('combo-clone');//selects all clones
```

Comment: Or `var original = document.querySelector('.combo');` ;)

Comment: I like the second alternative method.

Comment: I'll give you the comparison point. I was in the process of editing my code when you posted that comment though. Additionally, your implementation is wrong because it *only* works in the case where it is executed after the original node exists, but before the extra nodes are added. What if the original node is added sometime later after removeClones() is declared? My implementation is correct, because the user should pass a reference to the original node when requesting duplicates to be removed. Lastly, yes its a NodeList and not an array.  So you got that right, at least.

Comment: @chandru, you're welcome to accept whatever answer you want. But just be warned that this answer has a serious bug in it. Just be advised.

Comment: @Geuis: You can't clone an element that doesn't exist. I dont'know how the OP is going to implement this code, that's up to him. I just wrapped it in an IIFE to have a reference _enclosed_ along with the function to remove the clones. If the original doesn't exist, then he should create a function that _returns a closure_. As an aside: you were making edits to your post when I commented... bug whoop. So I copied your answer by telepathy? If you look at my comment again, too, you'll note that I never said that index !== 0 would avoid deleting the original node

Comment: I just suggested _not_ deleting _everything_. Ah well. If you think I stole your ideas, go ahead. There's probably a ton of people who feel that way. Some of them might be right, some might be wrong. I don't care. I will, however, remove this answer, and up-vote yours if you can show me how the alternative approach I offered is wrong, and how I _"stole"_ that idea from your answer...

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to the cloned elements somewhere (such as an array). Loop over that array and call `foo.parentNode.removeChild(foo)` on each value.

Comment: Or keep a single reference, to the original and use a `node === original` branch?